# DataSnap: update client dataset on updating server data

Tags: delphi, datasnap

In my server application I have some datasets, connected with TDataSetProvider
In client app, I use TClientDataSet

On some server methods, I changing SQL property of queries, and reloading data in server module.

But nothing changes on client app.

How to solve it in best way?

Thanks.

Comment: Use callbacks, client-pull or server-push to notify clients about the changes. Callbacks are supported in DataSnap afaik, client-pull can be implemented also in DS. Server-push without using callbacks could be done with a second channel, using TCP and a messaging protocol (MQTT, STOMP) or WebSockets.

Comment: Ok, I know from client side that server's dataset is updated. How should I refetch data from server. If I call ClientDataSet.Refresh it working, but server dataset is also refreshes again

Comment: Which Delphi version?  DataSnap in XE+ Delphi versions is a lot different than previously ...

Comment: I'm using Delphi XE5